# How to disable silent notifications on Huawei?

Tags: android, react-native, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-push-notification

Writing a `react-native` Huawei app with `"@hmscore/react-native-hms-push": "6.11.0-300"`, and I have this problem - all the notifications I receive when the app is on background are silent notifications (icon appears in tray, phone vibrates, but message is not displayed on top of the screen). My `HmsPushMessaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(...)` (set up before app launches) doesn't get triggered ever.

I tried adding the `<receiver>` to the android manifest as in [the docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/HMS-Plugin-Guides/receiving-data-messages-at-killed-state-0000001058199547-V1#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001058199547__li1811141617521), but no dice.

What am I missing? Running on EMUI 12.0.1.